# Turn off autocomplete in the App Script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

Can someone please, please, please tell me how to disable autocomplete in Google's App Script editor? I can type. When I can see what I'm typing into. That requires me to practically have a finger permanently on the Esc key to dismiss Google's "help."

This is cutting my typing speed in half and generally driving me bat-guano-crazy.